# What permission is required to remove or add resource lock for Azure SQL with Terraform on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-rbac

I have prod subscription where deploying pipeline fails because of permission missing.
My Azure AD user have no permission to create or remove locks of Azure SQL.

I wonder what and how to configure user permission so that Azure Pipeline can create, edit or remove resource locks?

TERRAFORM:

```
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "hellodb_lck" {
  for_each = var.databases
  name       = "can-not-delete"
  scope      = azurerm_sql_database.hellodb[each.key].id
  lock_level = "CanNotDelete"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json#who-can-create-or-delete-locks) shows that it's either the built-in Owner or User Access Administrator roles or custom roles with the right action, that are allowed to manipulate locks.

> To create or delete management locks, you must have access to `Microsoft.Authorization/*` or `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*` actions. Of the built-in roles, only Owner and User Access Administrator are granted those actions.

See [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72117523/16046045) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Your statement is not following what the docs state. It is [**or**] as it reads if you have access to `Microsoft.Authorization` **or** elevated access to the Owner or User Access Administrator.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing it out. Hopefully I've made it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json#who-can-create-or-delete-locks) the options on permissions to manage locks (each of these is an **or**):

- User account has elevated rights to the Owner or User Access Administrator role. These [two roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin#how-does-elevated-access-work) are part of the root tenant group for your Azure Tenant.
- User account has access to `Microsoft.Authorization/*`
- User account has access to `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*`

### Microsoft.Authorization Type

There are multiple different built-in roles and Resource permissions that allow a user to manipulate the locks on a resource.

A built-in role that has the required access would be [User Access Administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) as it is given Managed Authorization (aka `Microsoft.Authorization/*`).

As well, an Owner of a resource is granted `*` so it inherits the ability to control the locks on the resources as well. Anything under a Contributor on the resource itself does not have the required permissions as they are only given sub types of the `Microsoft.Authorization` (e.g. `Microsoft.Authorization/*/deletes`)